# How to upgrade Angular from V6 to V7 when the latest version is V8?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Usually, I upgrade Angular to the latest version but I have an old app in v6 that I would like to upgrade first to V7 first (which is not the latest).

The Angular documentation is not very clear:

> - Update to V7 of the core framework and CLI by running `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` in your terminal.
> - Update to V8 of the core framework and CLI by running `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` in your terminal

However `ng-update` always tries to update to the latest version.

Comment: Just curious... `that I would like to upgrade first to V7 first..` Any specific reason to **first** upgrade to 7 and not 8 in the first place?

Comment: I believe you'd need to specify the version using the `--to` flag and update a package at a time. see: [Angular CLI update Docs](https://angular.io/cli/update).

Comment: I got to many dependency errors with other packages I'm using. I want to do it gradually

Comment: I just answered. Let me know if that link helps!

Comment: Also, Anguar does not recommend moving across multiple major versions.

Comment: This blog may be usefull http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2021/05/upgrade-angular-version-to-latest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng update @angular/core@7.0.0  -- or whichever version you want to install.

You can also go into the package.json and update the core to the specific version you want and run `npm install`

Comment: Thanks i will try this once on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide on [upgrade.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/). You can set your current and desired version to whatever you want it to be. For 6.0 to 7.0 these are the steps at the very minimum:

1. npm install -g rxjs-tslint
2. rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
3. ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Comment: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` will automatically update you to v8 not v7

Comment: Oh good call. FYI - That info just came directly from their official upgrade site.

Comment: I know, I saw it